# Оставить в заголовке только название окна и кнопку закрыть

Tags: qt

Использую Qt 4.4.

Имеется диалог (QScrollArea). Необходимо кнопки свернуть и развернуть убрать. Оставить только title окна и кнопку закрыть. Как реализовать?

```
QWidget* runtimeRoot = new QWidget();
QScrollArea* mnemoScr1 = new QScrollArea(runtimeRoot);
mnemoScr1->setWindowFlags(Qt::Dialog);
mnemoScr1->setGeometry(0, 0, 200, 200);
runtimeRoot->show();
mnemoScr1->show();
```

Предполагаю, что нужно какой-то windowFlag добавить?

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите пример использования флагов [здесь](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qt-widgets-windowflags-example.html). Конечно этот пример написан для `Qt 4.8`, но на версии `4.4` тоже должен работать.

`tl;dr:` Попробуйте следующую комбинацию флагов: 
`mnemoScr1->setWindowFlags(Qt::Window | Qt::WindowCloseButtonHint);`

Answer (score 1):

Вот фрагмент рабочего кода - скопировал, вставил, заменил имена на свои:

```
YouWindow::YouWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::YouWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    setWindowFlags(windowFlags() & ~Qt::WindowContextHelpButtonHint); // убираем кнопку с вопросом
    ... // ваш дальнейший код
}
```